# Ruby Net::SSH multi-hop connection with individual authentication per hop

Tags: ruby, ssh

I am working on a Ruby script that is running on `Host 0`.
This host can see `Host 1`, which itself can see `Host 2`. But `Host 2` can't see `Host 0`.

`Host 0` -> `Host 1` -> `Host 2`

The goal is to establish an SSH connection between `Host 0` and `Host 2`, utilizing `Host 1`.

My current SSH config file looks like this:

```
host host1
Hostname host1.net
User user1

host host2
Hostname host2.net
User user2
ProxyCommand ssh host1.net -W %h:%p
```

The script looks like this:

```
Net::SSH.start('host2', 'user1', 
{:password => 'password1', :timeout => 5, :paranoid => false, :config => './config_file'}) do |ssh|
  result = ssh.exec!("hostname")
  puts result
end
```

This works fine for connecting to `Host 1`. Then this approach begins trying to connect to `Host 2`, but 'forgets' the `paranoid` parameter and does not supply a `password2`. It fails.

How can I make sure that the parameter `paranoid` and a `password2` are passed on for the second SSH hop from `Host 1` to `Host 2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works without a config file: The Net-SSH-Gateway project on GitHub (https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh-gateway)

It's integration allowed me to authenticate per hop like this:

```
gateway = Net::SSH::Gateway.new(hop_1["address"], hop_1["user"], {:password => hop_1["pass"], :timeout => 5, :paranoid => false})
    
    gateway.ssh(hop_2["address"], hop_2["user"], {:password => hop_2["pass"], :timeout => 8, :paranoid => false}) do |ssh|
      puts ssh.exec!("hostname")
    end

gateway.shutdown!
```